# How to improve Jaxb unmarshaller performance

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to marshal and unmarshal like below:
 I want to unmarshal xml from `<keyName>value</keyName>` to  HashMap

```
class A{
     private String name;

     private List<B> list;
    }

    class B{
     private Map <String, String> map;
    }
```

Xml:

```
<A>
  <name>name</name>
  <BList>
    <B>
      <key>value</key>
      <key>value</key>
    </B>
  </BList>
</A>
```

I want to unmarshal the xml to Class A. I was using  `@XmlAnyElement`. When I unmarshal A at with a large size XML `Blist.size=100000`, the performance is not ideal. What should I do to improve the performance?

Comment: Would you please explain wy you are using a Map? And where are the key values? Your XML snippet shows "key" and "value": does this mean you have many different XML elements with different local names replacing "key"? And why do you think that you need a List of B - the XML only shows a single B element. - Perhaps you present a "real" XML example?

Comment: e.g.has a map B{"someKey":"someValue"},the xml as below：<B><someKey>someValue</someKey>. xml's tag is map's key xml's value is map's value .The element would be known at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an XML snippet according to your description:

```
<doc>
  <data>
    <someKey>someValue</someKey>
    <otherKey>otherValue</otherKey>
  </data>
</doc>
```

This is the class for data's type:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MappingType", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class MappingType {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;

    public List<Object> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }
}
```

To unmarshal:

```
void unmarshal() throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( PACKAGE );
    Unmarshaller m = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<?> obj = (JAXBElement<?>)m.unmarshal( new File( XMLIN ) );
    DocType dt = (DocType)obj.getValue();
    MappingType mt = dt.getData();
    for( Object elobj: mt.getAny() ){
        System.out.println( "object: " + elobj.getClass() );
    }
    System.out.println( "done" );
}
```

Output

```
object: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
object: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
done
```

Processing the DOM elements is up to you, but what else can you expect?

Comment: thanks,laune,That I've done. I have another question,when when the list size  over 100000,the unmarshall spend too much time.Can this optimization?

Comment: This simple XML structure doesn't stress JAXB and Xerces very much, so I think that much of the time is spent with file i/o. If the XML can be compressed, reading that compressed file might be faster. See java,util.zip. Only a test will show you...

Comment: I spend one minute to convert a xml format String to object,I hope this faster